# $(x_1+x_2+x_3+\ldots+x_n)/(y_1+y_2+y_3+\ldots+y_n) = a$ and $x_1/y_1+x_2/y_2+\ldots+x_n/y_n = b$

Tags: correlation

I just have a interesting question:
When $(x_1+x_2+x_3+\ldots+x_n)/(y_1+y_2+y_3+\ldots+y_n) = a$ and $x_1/y_1+x_2/y_2+\ldots+x_n/y_n = b$
And all of $x_i$ and $y_i$ is positive float. 
How can I find any solition of ${x_1, x_2,\ldots,x_n}$ and ${y_1, y_2,\ldots,y_n}$? Is there any existing method to do this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What did you try?

Comment: In the simplest case, take $\frac{p+q}{r + s} = 1, \frac{p}{q} + \frac{r}{s} = 1$. There are no unique $p,q,r,s$ that satisfy these equations.

Comment: Yeah the simplest case is easy to solve, and I just want to know whether there is any other quick solution for any N

Comment: I just use python and try to test all of the possible x_i and y_i, and assume they are in number in range [1,100]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{cases}
(x_1+x_2+x_3+...+x_n)/(y_1+y_2+y_3+...+y_n) = a \\
 x_1/y_1 +x_2/y_2 + ...+x_n/y_n = b
\end{cases}\tag 1$$
Preliminary observation :

$$\text{Let : }\begin{cases}
U=x_2+x_3+...+x_n \\
V=y_2+y_3+...+y_n \\
W=x_2/y_2 + ...+x_n/y_n
\end{cases}\quad\implies\quad 
\begin{cases}
\frac{x_1+U}{y_1+V} = a \\
 \frac{x_1}{y_1} +W = b
\end{cases}\quad\implies$$
$$\begin{cases}
x_1=\frac{U-aV}{W+a-b}\\
y_1=\frac{(b-W)(U-aV)}{W+a-b}
\end{cases}$$
Method to find as many solutions as you want :
$$\begin{cases}
\text{Takes arbitrary } x_2,x_3,...,x_n \text{ and } y_2,y_3,...,y_n\\
\text{Compute } U,V,W\\
\text{Compute } x_1,y_1
\end{cases}$$
So, you get $(x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n \:;\: y_1, y_2,y_3,...,y_n)$ which satisfies the initial equations $(1)$.

Comment: Well, I think what you say is control variable method. Thanks you so much！